# Powershell - Remove everything but A-Z, - and space with Regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm pretty new to programming in powershell and regex in general. Can a kind soul please explain to me why the following doesn't work?

```
while($true) {
    $Name = Read-Host "Please enter your firstname and lastname"

    if($Name -match "[^a-zA-Z-]" -and $Name -match " ") {
        break;
    } else {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor red "You didn't enter a valid name! Please try again."
    }
}
```

I want my code to keep asking for first and surname as long as it has characters that are not a-z and - along with a space in it. Am I taking the wrong approach here?

Woops, should probably have mentioned the error. I can add numbers and special symbols (like ><\^€$ etc.). It only gives me the error in else when I'm not adding in a space in the $name string

Comment: Woops, should probably have mentioned the error. I can add numbers and special symbols (like ><\^€$ etc.). It only gives me the error in else when I'm not adding in a space in the $name string

Comment: Not very clear. What's allowed and required. Forget about what's _not allowed_.

Comment: To be clear, you want to keep asking for a first and last name until (1) there are no non-alphabetic characters in it and (2) it has a space in it?

Comment: im pretty sure you need to escape the `-` character with a `\\`

Comment: @RNar Not if it's at the beginning or end of a character class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to match a single space total not just a single space using regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160735/how-to-match-a-single-space-total-not-just-a-single-space-using-regular-expressi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned you need to add the + qualifier to your character class to match one or more characters. You also need to add an expression to catch the last name.

```
while($true)
{
    $Name = Read-Host "Please enter your firstname and lastname"

    if($Name -match "^[a-zA-Z-]+\s[a-zA-Z-]+$")
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor red "You didn't enter a valid name! Please try again."
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me understand this and solving my problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match a string of only lowercase and uppercase Latin characters and hyphens, this is what you want:

```
^[a-z -]+$
```

If you want to prevent more than one space in a  row, you have to do something a little more complicated:

```
^(?:[a-z-]+ ?)+$
```

Though I'm not as familiar with Bash as I thought, so that might not be totally accurate.

What you have checks if there are any characters that aren't in that character class (because you negate it with `^`), and only returns true if that's the case.

Comment: FYI `-match`, and related regex comparison operators,  by default is case insensitive. That last part is not valid syntax either for PowerShell

Comment: @Matt Whoops. I should probably get back to using Unix and practice a little.

Comment: With this, it still exists the while loop once there's atleast an alphabetic character or hyphen and a space in the string, meaning it still accepts my $Name string if it is "Erik \^"

Comment: @ErikJ Hm, then `-match` works the other way from what I thought. I'm about to edit it to work.

Comment: ^(?:[a-z -]+ ?)+$ will allow more than one space, as well as more than two names.

Comment: @swestner Yes, but it won't allow more than one in a row. Like I said.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes The space in the character class allows an unlimited number of consecutive spaces. Removing it will give a better result, but would still match a trailing space. Also, the + quantifier after the non capturing group allows an unlimited number of names to be matched. If you do not want to repeat the character class (which i initially tried to avoid), the closest way I can see is (?:[a-zA-Z-]+\s?){2}, but that would still match a trailing space after the last name, resulting in 2 possible spaces. The OP stated only a space was wanted, so thats a no go.

Comment: @swestner Oh, whoops. That's a typo. It's fixed now.